# Why does 11.04 boot so slow on my system?

Tags: 11.04, unity, boot, compiz, command-line

I downloaded Ubuntu 11.04 and it was working fine until I started tweaking compiz and rebooted. It took 3 to 4 minutes to boot up. When I press enter at the boot menu, there is a black screen with something flickering on the top left corner, which is normal, but for me the black screen stays for 4 to 5 mins. It is driving me crazy. Please explain your answer as I am not the terminal stuff.

Comment: start with looking at your '`dmesg`' output after bootup. It shows '`/var/log/dmesg'` which records the timestamps with logs as your system comes up.

Comment: also on the os selection screen (grub) press e (edit) and remove the words 'quiet' and 'splash' from the list of options, then try booting. this will might show you what your computer is doing for that extra time.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to trace down the issue by installing bootchart available in repos.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootchart

Answer (score 1):

I'm on 11.10 with `nvidia-current` drivers.
From my boot chart I've found out that booting into Unity 3D lasted 1:12.98 min while booting into Unity 2D took 0:38.66 min.

So I decided to look if some processes related to nVidia differ in both boots.
And indeed I found out that `nvidia-settings` process was mentioned `proc_ps.log` in such proportion:

- 66 times for Unity 3D and
- 21 times for Unity 2D.

That lead me to conclusion that disabling `nvidia-settings` may improve boot performance.
So I did `sudo chmod a-x /usr/bin/nvidia-settings` and the next boot in Unity 3D took the same 37 seconds (0:37.76) as with Unity 2D.

For sure it is not the solution, but at least a direction to look.

Hope this helps.

P.S. Make sure you know what are you doing while dealing with system files.